# Is there any way to know if a polygon is part of another bigger polygon(s) in SQL server?

Tags: polygon, sql-server, geometry, polygon-creation

Basicaly, what I am trying to do is we have a lot of geographical containers like territories, sub-territories etc. and the boundaries of each keep on changing all the times and I have to store the heirarchial data in to regular SQL using adjecent lists which says

> Territory A is parent of sub-territory B

Now, I was thinking that I can replace the entire thing if I can store each territory as a polygon in the map and make SQL responsible for finding which sub-territory is sub-geographical region of which Territory.

However, my knowledge of Geospatial data is next to basic and I wanted to know if SQL can do following for me:

- Find out which territory(polygon) is a sub-territory(sub-polygon) of another one
- If it can find which other territories have overlapping geographical definitions then that is fine too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is stored in your SQL Server database as native spatial data, you can certainly do this.

Assuming your territories (T) and sub-territories (ST) have attributes for their name and/or type, my suggestion would be along the lines of:

Create a view (a dynamic table in your database) that joins your two polygons together using a join, where the join condition uses the STIntersects function on the T.shape and ST.shape.

Now that your tables are 'spatially joined', you can call attributes from either table in your select statement that contains the T and ST names.

What you have is a table containing the original T values, and the name of the ST they belong to.

You do, however, have to consider how these polygons overlap - are all the ST's completely within the T's? Would you rather know if the centroid of the ST falls within a T (if so, use the STIntersect on the STCentroid of the polygons to do a point in polygon join)...

Another issue, especially with SQL Server, is the editing of the data. We currently use ArcGIS as the 'spatial client' of our SQL Server Spatial data. We use FME to ETL our data into ArcGIS for editing, then ETL it back into SQL Server (though you can use QGIS as an editing client...).

But... it can all be done!

Here are the SQL spatial functions you have access to with Geometry data type: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933960.aspx